# public function to create and open a database connection

Tags: database, vb.net, postgresql, connection

I have a client/server desktop application that I am having some database connection issues with on some of my clients pc's. When I wrote the app, I didn't know any better so I created and opened 1 database connection on application startup, and used that same connection all throughout the app. I know realize this is a bad idea since shaky network connections and it seems antivirus programs are causing these connection to be dropped at times, leading to some errors. I have hundreds of places in code where I need to go back and create/open/close the connection at the time they are being used.

The question is, is there any way to create a public function in which I can do just that, and then do a global find and replace to replace the connection name with the new function name?

something like:

```
 Dim qry As NpgsqlCommand
 sqlUpdateItem = "update table set field = value where id = 1"
 qry = New NpgsqlCommand(sqlUpdateItem, con)
 qry.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

to

```
 Dim qry As NpgsqlCommand
 sqlUpdateItem = "update table set field = value where id = 1"
 qry = New NpgsqlCommand(sqlUpdateItem, newCon())
 qry.ExecuteNonQuery()

public function newCon()
    Dim con As New NpgsqlConnection(connectionString)
    con.Open()
    Return tcon
End Function
```

I tried this but no luck. I'm just looking for any possible solutions that don't involve me updating several lines of code in hundreds of places throughout my app. The nice thing is I would only need to do this for all commands, since I can pass a brand new connection into a data adapter and it will handle the opening/closing.

Comment: You may want to leave room for the possibility of still other issues and improvements.  Many of the db Provider objects ought to be created, used and *disposed*, for instance.  `Option Strict` is another,

Comment: Your existing connection was never being disposed of. If you now create a new connection for each of these they will never be disposed of either and eventually you'll run out of connections. As @Plutonix stated take the time now to do a little refactoring. Have a look at the `using` statement for  a clear way of disposing these objects.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how I'd recommend you attempt it.

1. Enable option strict in your project. It's better to have your errors at compile time than at runtime.
2. Use a using statement to safely dispose of the database classes even if you get an exception.

---

```
Private _connectionString As String = "blah"

Public Function GetDbConnection() As NpgsqlConnection
    Dim con As New NpgsqlConnection(_connectionString)
    con.Open()
    Return con
End Function

Public Sub DoMyQuery()
    Using conn = GetDbConnection()
        Using qry = New NpgsqlCommand("update table set field = value where id = 1", conn)
            qry.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: Looks like i'll be stuck updating code in every place my connection is used then.. thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Yeah, you'll need to change something in every spot anyway. And if you're going to test everything once, it may as well be done right.